# My code is stuck in a loop involving Serial.read. How can I break this?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

So I'm running a program that involves both Arduino and a Raspberry PI and they are communicating between the Serial port. As you can see below when my an emergency stop door, involving a magnetic switch, is opened then the PI sends a message to the Arduino. When the door is closed the PI sends a different value telling the Arduino to continue with the program. The Arduino is receiving and reading the messages correctly as I have ran a few tests with the serial monitor.

When the door is open the PI is printing '1' which shuts down the Arduino correctly. My problem is that when I close the doors nothing happens when in theory it should break the loop and continue to run the main Arduino code. The raspberry PI is correctly printing '2' and the Arduino is correctly reading this value as it prints "Logoff" in the serial monitor.

If anyone can help or lead me to correctly breaking this loop and returning to the main code that would be great.

Thanks.

Below is the emergency part of the code that continues to run. If the full code is needed I will gladly edit it into this post. Also if the PI code is needed I will post that too, I don't believe is necessary because there are no problems on that side.

```
void Estop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        int d = Serial.read() - '0';

        while (d == 1) {
            digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(red, LOW);
            digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(estopout, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(piston, LOW);
            digitalWrite(belt, HIGH);
            Serial.read() - '0';
            Serial.print(d);
            delay(2000);
            break;

            if (d == 0) {
                Serial.print("Logoff");
                delay(2000);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I have reformatted your code so it indents properly. It then becomes much easier to see the flow of logic. I have a feeling the whole way you are doing what you are wanting to do is flawed. A proper description of what exactly it is you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: What does this line prints? `Serial.print(d);`

Answer (score 1):

You never reassigned the variable d anywhere within the loop. The `while` breaks after a 2 seconds delay after printing what is the value of d. That means that your `if (d == 0) [...]` never gets hit. I presume that you expect to read 'logoff' on your code?

```
void Estop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        int d = Serial.read() - '0';

        while (d == 1) {
            digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(red, LOW);
            digitalWrite(blue, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(estopout, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(piston, LOW);
            digitalWrite(belt, HIGH);
            d = Serial.read() - '0';
            Serial.print(d);
            delay(2000);
            #break;

            if (d == 0) {
                Serial.print("Logoff");
                delay(2000);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your while loop, **you never change the condition**, running into an infinite while loop.

Further: Your program does not delay until `d` equals `0` or `1`. This can be problematic as `d` can have other values. It is an `int`.

**Plus**, you do a `while` loop while `d` equals `1` and ask, if `d` equals `0` without changing the value of `d` in between. Your `if` would never be true.

I also don't know, what this line should do:

```
int d = Serial.read() - '0';
```

did you mean:

```
int d = Serial.read();
```

I dont't see any sense, to subtract `0` from your the value you read.

Comment: The line that subtracts '0' converts the script coming form the PI into a value that the Arduino can read. So should i change the while to an if statement?

Comment: `'0'` is the ASCII value, so subtracting turns a ASCII number into its corresponding integer.  It is basically `atoi(Serial.read())` that is only valid for the characters 0-.